# execute bat script in JAVA

Tags: java

I want to execute bat script . the script is placed in the same location as the JAVA classes.
here is the code

```
           ClassLoader loader = WebController.class.getClassLoader();
           URL resource = loader.getResource("a.bat");
           Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(resource.getPath() + clusterName);
           proc.waitFor();
```

clusterName is the argument which is being passed to bat script.

However, the `resource` object is coming as null and bat script is not executing
not sure what is the correct syntax of putting a.bat.

My understanding is, a.bat is in the same package where all the JAVA classes are there , so I dont have to mention any relative path .
please suggest

Comment: Exec expects a path of a file in a filesystem. What is the value of `resource.getPath()`?

Comment: You can't execute a resource as a Windows batch file. You would have to save the resource somewhere first as a file and then execute it as a batch file. Use `ProcessBuilder` with `inheritIO` to do that

Comment: Is there any way to mention the relative path ? I dont want to hard code full path

Comment: Yes, *In a sense* they are all relative anyway as they are urls off a classpath. If it's at the root, I would use a form of `"/a.bat"`

Comment: Actually it's not *inconceivable* that you could do it without creating a file but I wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to bring it as a resource. Simply do this:

```
  Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/full/path/a.bat " + clusterName);
           proc.waitFor();
```

Comment: Unless it’s packaged as a resource.

Comment: I dont want to hard code the full path . can we have relative path ? 
as it is in same package , is there any way to just use relative path ? @Michael

Comment: You will need to find out what is your home directory for java execution. You can use relative path to your home directory. Also, if the path to your a.bat file is included in your PATH than you can just use "a.bat"

Comment: As @DaveNewton mentioned, if the application/resources are packaged into a jar file this will not work.

Comment: Than I would suggest read the file from your JAR and write it into some temp folder on disk, run it and than delete it

Comment: I think you'd **have** to do that; I don't see how the command line could run something that isn't exposed as a file *(or string, I guess)*.